# Unable to ask new questions or edit questions from Internet Explorer 11

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, asking-questions, internet-explorer

A very recent change that has been deployed is preventing me from asking new questions or editing existing questions using Internet Explorer 11. (Yes, it is a [supported browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need).)

When asking a new question or editing an existing one, the tag bar appears in plain text, and the submit button is always disabled.

> [image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371290/tags-arent-working-correctly-when-writing-or-editing-a-question (appears to also affect Safari, though I can't say which version(s))

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think in [tageditornew.en.js](http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/tageditornew.en.js?v=8981fe7b960e) this line needs fixing: `editor.addClass("s-input").css({paddingTop: 0, paddingTop: 0});` the double paddingTop is not allowed.

Comment: yep, that's it @rene

Comment: blame a relaxed jslint rule ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As rene pointed out in the comments, this appears to have been triggered by a newly-added bit of code in the tag editor which tries to set the same property twice in a single call.

That's... likely a typo; I changed one of the `paddingTop` properties to `paddingBottom` and the page loads on IE just fine.

This fix should now be live.

Comment: Correct CSS is "padding-top", not "paddingTop" - no? Unless CSS changed drastically since I learned the basics and it allows JS style syntax? Anyway, guess jQuery changes it by itself otherwise it wouldn't be working at all, just neat picking here. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The DOM style properties JS interacts with are camel case.

Comment: CSS also doesn't care about duplicate rules, @Shadow. The jQuery call - `.css({style properties})` - takes an object, and JS sometimes does mind duplicate object properties. Note also that while the CSS property is `padding-top`, the equivalent DOM property *is* [paddingTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference) - not that this is relevant.

Comment: Well, I'm using that `.css({style properties})` myself sometimes, but always gave the "CSS case",  not JS camelCase. Admit that I never looked into it, just seemed like the proper way. Anyhow... thanks for the quick fix, on behalf of all the IE11 users! :) (Which I'm not among them.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard jQuery allows you to pass properties either as camelCase or as in CSS. It then internally converts the names into camelCase.