# Option to hide the "Sorry, we no longer support Internet Explorer" banner?

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar, internet-explorer

Recently, official support for Internet Explorer ended. Ref this question (status-complete):

[Maybe it's time to formally drop support for IE 11](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322637/maybe-its-time-to-formally-drop-support-for-ie-11)

Due to dumb IT policies at work, out of my control, Internet Explorer is the only browser available to me. I'm a regular user of the site, and now I have to see this banner every time I visit, on every page I visit - without being able to close the banner or update my browser!

[image: banner]

I understand the move to drop official support, and I understand the need for a banner, but can you **please** add a close button which hides it for at least the current browser session?

By example, Github has a similar message with a helpful "Ignore" button:

[image: Github banner]

Comment: @Mark thanks - I didn't find that dupe before posting

Comment: As an aside, from someone who works (and has worked) at a place with similar policy, have you considered portable versions of your favourite browser? I'm posting this from portable Firefox and it runs SE a heck of a lot better than IE does.

Comment: Why are they sorry that they don't support it though? :)

Comment: @Mast The policies are there for a reason - part "vetted software = OK", part "IP protection enforcement". I'd likely risk my job if I started running portable versions.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. We don't share that risk.

Comment: For my job, the only reason we have internet is that our database access is via internet-type apps, and for development reasons (including accessibility, back-compatibility, slow rollouts across the country), we're also on Win10 at all of HQ, but regional offices are mostly Win7.  We tried a project using an app developed by another gov't agency, and because they ONLY tested on Chrome, they missed all the usability/accessibility issues that clean coding would have solved.  (A lot of our employees have vision/mobility impairments)